# Where should I ask questions about beautiful web site design?

Tags: support

Where should I ask this kind of questions?

> any sites like htmldrive.net?
>
> I am looking for sites which showing demos of js,css,or php.
>   such as http://htmldrive.net. verry wonderful site collecting the demos of js.
>   any one collects these type of sites,can you write down ?

I am not clear as to why my question was closed. My English is not good. I was confused when researching the "how to ask question" document.

If Stack Overflow is not the appropriate site to ask this kind of questions, what would be?

Comment: The SO question the OP is referring to is [where to find beatiful web sites?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768966/where-to-find-beatiful-web-sites).

Comment: Actually, OP seems to be referring to a Meta question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109366/any-sites-like-htmldrive-net @Dori

Comment: @waiwai933 - I saw that one (which is why I brought this up at all), but the question on SO came first, and he particularly asked about SO.

Comment: At UX.stackexchange.com we're a big fan of beautiful design, but it's more complcaited than just "pretty sites," you'll have to be more specific about what sort of interlace you're looking for there..

Comment: htmldrive itself is anything *but* beautiful.

Comment: *Daft Punk has a beatiful website.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your particular question can never have a single concrete answer. It leads only to open and endless discussion and polling. You're looking for a discussion forum. Stack Overflow isn't a discussion forum. It's a Question & Answer site. See also the site FAQ: https://stackoverflow.com/faq

For example http://forums.devshed.com is a discussion forum. I'm however not sure if this kind of questions are also appreciated over there. You may want to explore their FAQ first.

Comment: thank you very much,I asked several questions at http://forums.devshed.com before . but few people answer , it seems  a cold forums.